# How to get system default gateway address in Linux + windows + MAC

Tags: linux, windows, macos, gateway

I have found a way to get default gateway in Linux with the following command:

> `grep -i "gateway" /etc/network/interfaces | awk print $2`

Output:

> `192.168.14.1`

This will not work if the system is in DHCP mode.

I need a way to get only 'gateway' which works on all platforms (Linux / Windows / Mac).

Comment: here is the usefull Link, https://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/Find_Your_Gateway_IP

Comment: In Linux :  ip route | grep default | awk {'print $3'}
In Windows : ipconfig | findstr /i "default Gateway" | findstr [0-9]

Comment: Please do not add `[SOLVED]` or any similar wordings to the title of the question. If your problem is solved, you only need to write an answer and accept it.

Comment: There is a cross platform python library for network information -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for Linx(your host may be dhcp or static)

route -n | cut -d" " -f10

Output : x.x.x.x(gateway address)

Comment: For Windows : for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %i  in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /i "Default gateway" ^| findstr [0-9]') do echo %i

Comment: For Linux : ip route | grep default | awk {'print $3'}

Comment: For MAC : netstat -nr | grep default | awk {'print $2'}

Comment: Please click "edit" underneath your answer to include the other cases.  Answers are more permanent than comments.

Answer (score 0):

How to Find Default Gateway IP Address on Linux?
Here's the solution:

1. Click the Settings icon on the left side bar.
2. On the settings side bar, scroll down, and click Network option. Select connection settings icon.
3. Find your gateway IP address listed next to Default Route.
   You're done.

Reference:

https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-find-your-default-gateway-ip-address-2626072
https://www.purevpn.com/what-is-my-ip/default-gateway
https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/finding-your-default-gateway/

Answer (score -1):

**For Windows using Control Panel:**

**Step 1:** Type Control Panel in the Windows search box (usually located at the bottom left of the screen), and hit Enter when it appears.

**Step 2:** Click the Network and Internet.

**Step 3:** Click the Network and Sharing Center.

**Step 4:** Under the Network and Sharing Center window, click Ethernet.

**Step 5:** Click Details.

**Step 6:** Find your gateway IP address listed next to IPv4 Default Gateway.

Comment: I think the OP meant getting the default gateway programmatically (not through the OS UI)

Comment: oh yeah. thanx buddy :)